# Python SELENIUM issue

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

```
</form></table>
<br>
 <table><tr><th>Login With Password:
    <tr><td class=w><form method=POST action="/do_login">
       User Name: <input name="name" type="text">
       &nbsp; Password: <input name="password" type="password">
       <input type="submit" value="Login">
       <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="">
</form></table>
```

I would like to also post the hidden field doing log in, and selenium only allows me to use the send_key function with only field that are enabled and displayed.

Without posting the input hidden value doing log in, it won't log in, I was able to do it with requests module with the data parameter in the request.post() function, but Id like to it with selenium.i need to post the "redirect" as well...it is compulsory for signing in...please help
here is the code...

```
driver.find_element_by_name("name").send_keys("hhhhh")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("hhhh")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']").submit()
```

Comment: Can you write down what you have done so far?

Comment: in what sense??sorry i dont seem to understand what you meant by that...

Comment: As I see it, the moment you submit the form, it will POST everything that is between the `<form> </form>` so makes no sense it is not. Have you tried writing some selenium code to check what error it gives you?

Comment: i just edited and included the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try modifying the attribute value of the tag from `"hidden"` to `"text"` by executing a script on the browser via `execute_script()`and then use `send_keys()`.

```
s = "something"
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('redirect')[0].setAttribute('type', 'text');")
driver.find_element_by_name("redirect").send_keys(s)
```

Or you could just enter your data into the tag by the following script:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('redirect')[0].value = '" + s + "';")
```

Comment: @samlexxy - Sure, let me know if you still face an issue. If the answer helps, do accept it with a green tick. :)