# Python Selenium Element does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Been struggling to click a certain nested li in a ul. Each attempt throws an error. Im trying to use xpath however any approach would be welcome. Also take into consideration that there is some extra text after the span tag.

Script:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()=contains(span,'Tomorrow')]").click()
```

HTML

```
 <ul class="slide-flow">
 <li class="slide-flow__item">....</li>
 <li class="slide-flow__item">
 <div>
 <label class="radio" for="pack 2" data-track="2nd track">
 <div class="slide-flow__menu menu_brand">
 <strong>
 <span>Tomorrow</span>
 </strong>
 -Second Notataion
 </label>
 <span class="slide-flow__price">...</span>
 </div>
 </li>
 <li class="slide-flow__item"> ....</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this part of html is not inside an iframe!? In that case you should first switch to iframe.

Comment: Nope, no iframes involved here. I wish that would of been the case.

Comment: THen please share the exact error message that you get and more piece of html.

Answer (score 1):

1. The spelling of "Tomorrow" is different in the XPath and HTML.
2. In `contains()` function, try `contains(., 'Tommorow')`. Replace `span` with `.`.

Correct XPath will be (Check the spelling of "Tomorrow")

```
//label[text()=contains(.,'Tommorow')]
```

Comment: Let me check that out

Comment: Same error using //label[text()=contains(.,'Tommorow')]

Comment: @PeterCunningham - Is that `span` tag within an `iframe`?

Comment: Nope its not. Very strange indeed. I would be glad if I could execute the click using javascript

Comment: @PeterCunningham - Well, you can try something on these lines - [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33829604/2932244). Using `execute_script()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the entirety of the text in the SPAN is "Tommorow" (misspelled), you don't need `contains()`. The below works.

```
//span[text()='Tommorow']
```

Comment: Thanks alot this got to work with the right spelling.